# Can one use a standard package-installed etcd rather than install-etcd.sh?

Tags: kubernetes, etcd

The Community guide to GitHub Workflow has a short section on how to install etcd in K8s, by running hack/install-etcd.sh. But I'm running Fedora, which has what appears to be a perfectly respectable (and even newer) etcd package. Is there anything about the Fedora package that would be incompatible with the content installed by install-etcd.sh?

Answer (score 0):

By default, it looks for pre-installed etcd, [it just validates the version](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/hack/lib/etcd.sh#L23:13) and after that, if it [can't find the etcd](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/hack/lib/etcd.sh#L103:13), it will download the binary, so any way you can install the etcd [from package manager](https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=etcd) but version should be 3.1.12 or newest (for now)

Comment: OK, so the newer version on my Fedora system, 3.2.16, is currently not technically compatible? That's useful to know.

Comment: No it is compatible, you can use any version 3.1.12 or newest